# Constantipolitan only for per-site metas?

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2012

I like the [Constantipolitan hat](http://winterba.sh/constantipolitan), but I didn't earn it after posting an answer on meta (maybe I'll get it after this question?).

So, is it only for per-site metas, or should it work on meta.stackoverflow.com too?

I want that hat!

Comment: Might I suggest: earn it on another site, screencap your gravatar wearing it, and then make it your MSO-only gravatar? :D

Comment: @false [meta-tag:hats] was more fun!

Comment: See [tag:winterbash] : For questions about the Winter Bash (or holiday hats) ...

Comment: Have you seen @Aarthi's hat: This is special - it is even visible "from outside" also for anonymous users.

Comment: @false You have to opt-in user-by-user on SO -- but hats are on by default on MSO! :D

Comment: @Aarthi - reassuring, thought you were hatter than us!

Comment: @false *gasp* Never, good sir!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed now -- [Constantipolitan](http://winterba.sh/constantipolitan) is being correctly awarded on Stack Overflow.

The bug was caused by the fact that Meta Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow have somewhat of a special relationship, in that your MSO user id does not necessarily equal your SO user id (unlike other meta/parent sites).

Comment: I got mine earlier, presumably because my MSO id **is** the same as my SO id. (Yes I have been around that long).

Answer (score 1):

But have you seen my Constantipolitan hat?  I seem to have misplaced it.

Comment: You need to have a post (question or answer) on Meta with score of 1 or more. You don't have such yet.

Comment: Earn an upvote on meta?  Impossible

Comment: Here, take an upvote.